# Issue when comparing lpcs->lpszName with other value like "OLEChannelWnd" in a WH_CBT callback

Tags: c++, setwindowshookex

Below is the code of my `WH_CBT` callback. I am trying to ignore any click of a hyperlink in Outlook. When I click a hyperlink in Outlook, I'm getting a message box:

[image]

But when I return `1` in the callback without the `if` condition, it works fine.

```cpp
LRESULT __declspec(dllexport)__stdcall  CALLBACK GetCBTProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    HRESULT hResult;
    

    if (nCode < 0)
        CallNextHookEx(hkb, nCode, wParam, lParam);

    HWND parentWin;
    DWORD ChiledThreadID;
    DWORD parentProcessID = 0;
    std::ostringstream streamcb;
    DWORD xx = (DWORD)15028;
    HWND hCurrWnd;

    TCHAR  clsName_v[22];
    TCHAR  className[22]="OleMainThreadWndClass";
    LPCSTR oleName2 = _T("OLEChannelWnd");
    int number;
    f1 = fopen("C:\\Log\\report.txt", "a+");
    if (nCode == HCBT_CREATEWND)
    {
        hCurrWnd = (HWND)wParam;
        parentWin = GetAncestor(hCurrWnd, GA_ROOT);
        ChiledThreadID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(parentWin, &parentProcessID);
        if (parentProcessID == xx)
        {
            writetofile("HCBT_CREATEWND", 15, f1);

            CBT_CREATEWNDA* cw = (CBT_CREATEWNDA*)lParam;
            CREATESTRUCTA* lpcs = (CREATESTRUCTA*)cw->lpcs;

            number = GetClassName(hCurrWnd, clsName_v, 22);
            writetofile(clsName_v, number, f1);

            if (lpcs->lpszName)
            {
                if (CompareString(LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, 0, lpcs->lpszName, -1, _T("OLEChannelWnd"), 13) == CSTR_EQUAL)
                {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(f1);

    LRESULT RetVal = CallNextHookEx(hkb, nCode, wParam, lParam);

    return  RetVal;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is missing two `return` statements, one on the `CallNextHookEx()`, and one at the end of the callback. So, the return value of the callback is *indeterminate* unless the input string matches your criteria. Your compiler should have warned you about the second missing `return`. A function with a non-`void` return type must exit with a `return <value>;` statement.

Try this instead:

```cpp
LRESULT __declspec(dllexport) CALLBACK GetCBTProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode == HCBT_CREATEWND)
    {
        HWND hCurrWnd = (HWND) wParam;
        HWND parentWin = GetAncestor(hCurrWnd, GA_ROOT);
        DWORD parentProcessID = 0;
        DWORD ChildThreadID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(parentWin, &parentProcessID);
        const DWORD xx = 8108;

        if (parentProcessID == xx)
        {
            FILE *f1 = fopen("C:\\Log\\report.txt", "a+");

            writetofile("HCBT_CREATEWND", 14, f1);

            CBT_CREATEWND* cw = (CBT_CREATEWND*) lParam;
            CREATESTRUCT* lpcs = (CREATESTRUCT*) cw->lpcs;

            TCHAR clsName_v[22] = {};
            int number = GetClassName(hCurrWnd, clsName_v, 22);
            writetofile(clsName_v, number, f1);

            fclose(f1);

            if (lpcs->lpszName)
            {
                if (CompareString(LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, 0, lpcs->lpszName, -1, _T("OLEChannelWnd"), 13) == CSTR_EQUAL)
                {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(hkb, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: You alright, the callback is there but I forgot to added to the Q. I changed the code as as you suggested but still getting the message from outlook.

Comment: @Mohammad I made a minor tweak to my example, see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks Remy, I tried it but same issue getting message box from outlook. I found work around by discard the message box from the callback.